# Persist data fetched in Nextjs' getServerSideProps to rest of app without having to re-fetch on page load

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, react-state-management

I have an index page that includes data fetching within `getServerSideProps`.

If I use `next/link` or maybe `router.push()` - Is there a way for that data to persist across to the rest of the pages in my app?

Or is this a scenario where I'd need to use something like Context/Redux?

For example:

**index.tsx**

```
const App = ({ productData }: IndexProps) => {
  return (
    <Link href={`/product/${title}`}> ... </Link>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const productData = await getProducts();

  return {
    props: { productData },
  };
};
```

**/product/[id].tsx**

```
const Product = ({ productData }) => {
  return (
    <Link href={`/product/${title}`}> ... </Link>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {

  if (PRODUCTDATADOESNTEXIST) {
    const productData = await getProducts();
  }
  
// else use data fetched in from previous page?

  return {
    props: { productData },
  };
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service that will cache the data in memory.

Something like this.

```
const cache = {};

export const setProducts = (products) => {
    products.forEach((p) => {
        cache[p.id] = p;
    });
};


const getProduct = (id) {

    if(cache[id]){
        Promise.resolve(cache[id]);
        
    }
    // make the API call to fetch data; 

}

export default getProduct;
```

Use the set method to store the data from the NextJS Page and use the get method to fetch data when needed.